# Resolve System.DmlException: Insert failed. INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY, insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []

Tags: apex, unit-test

Getting these stack messages

> Class.TestDataFactory.InsertTestData: line 166, column 1
> Class.OrderTests.SetupTestData: line 7, column 1

As I am logged in as Salesforce Admin in my sandbox, I should not get this error while sharing record. Any ideas how to resolve the error in below test code?

Checked the access, I have full access in PricebookEntry standard object

also checked the below scenbarios mentioned in URL https://www.forcetree.com/2011/12/insufficientaccessoncrossreferenceentit.html

> NOTE: A common cause for this issue is the below scenario. Read on, if that's not the case for you.
> *If you are trying to share "Record X" with "User Y" and "User Y" already has access to "Record X" this error happens.

=============OrderTests.apxc=========================

```
            @isTest
            private class OrderTests {
                static User testUser;
                
                @testSetup
                static void SetupTestData() {
                    TestDataFactory.InsertTestData(20);
                    testUser = TestDataFactory.CreateTestUser(); // create a test user with necessary permissions
                }
                
                @isTest
                static void OrderUpdate_UnitTest() {
                    // create the test data as the test user
                    System.runAs(testUser) {
                        Order selectedOrder = [Select name,Status, Id from Order limit 1];
                        Product2 oldProd = [Select Quantity_Ordered__c, Name, Id from Product2 limit 1];
                        
                        selectedOrder.Status = Constants.ACTIVATED_ORDER_STATUS;
                        update selectedOrder;
                        
                        Product2 updatedProd = [Select Quantity_Ordered__c, Name, Id from Product2 limit 1];
                        
                        TestDataFactory.VerifyQuantityOrdered(oldProd,updatedProd,Constants.DEFAULT_ROWS);
                    }
                }
                
                @isTest
                static void OrderExtension_UnitTest() {
                    // create the test data as the test user
                    System.runAs(testUser) {
                        PageReference reference = Page.OrderEdit;
                        Test.setCurrentPage(reference);
                        Order CurOrder = [Select Id,Status from Order limit 1];
                        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new Apexpages.StandardController(CurOrder);
                        OrderExtension extension = new OrderExtension(controller);
                        System.assertEquals(5, extension.orderItemList.size());
                        extension.selectedFamily = 'Dessert';
                        extension.SelectFamily();
                        extension.OnFieldChange();
                        extension.First();
                        extension.Next();
                        extension.Previous();
                        extension.Last();
                        extension.GetHasNext();
                        extension.GetPageNumber();
                        extension.GetHasPrevious();
                        extension.GetTotalPages();
                        extension.GetFamilyOptions();
                        extension.Save();
                        ChartHelper.GetInventory();
                    }
                } 
            }
```

============================TestDataFactory.aspxc====================

```
            @isTest
            private class OrderTests {
                static User testUser;
                
                @testSetup
                static void SetupTestData() {
                    TestDataFactory.InsertTestData(20);
                    testUser = TestDataFactory.CreateTestUser(); // create a test user with necessary permissions
                }
                
                @isTest
                static void OrderUpdate_UnitTest() {
                    // create the test data as the test user
                    System.runAs(testUser) {
                        Order selectedOrder = [Select name,Status, Id from Order limit 1];
                        Product2 oldProd = [Select Quantity_Ordered__c, Name, Id from Product2 limit 1];
                        
                        selectedOrder.Status = Constants.ACTIVATED_ORDER_STATUS;
                        update selectedOrder;
                        
                        Product2 updatedProd = [Select Quantity_Ordered__c, Name, Id from Product2 limit 1];
                        
                        TestDataFactory.VerifyQuantityOrdered(oldProd,updatedProd,Constants.DEFAULT_ROWS);
                    }
                }
                
                @isTest
                static void OrderExtension_UnitTest() {
                    // create the test data as the test user
                    System.runAs(testUser) {
                        PageReference reference = Page.OrderEdit;
                        Test.setCurrentPage(reference);
                        Order CurOrder = [Select Id,Status from Order limit 1];
                        ApexPages.StandardController controller = new Apexpages.StandardController(CurOrder);
                        OrderExtension extension = new OrderExtension(controller);
                        System.assertEquals(5, extension.orderItemList.size());
                        extension.selectedFamily = 'Dessert';
                        extension.SelectFamily();
                        extension.OnFieldChange();
                        extension.First();
                        extension.Next();
                        extension.Previous();
                        extension.Last();
                        extension.GetHasNext();
                        extension.GetPageNumber();
                        extension.GetHasPrevious();
                        extension.GetTotalPages();
                        extension.GetFamilyOptions();
                        extension.Save();
                        ChartHelper.GetInventory();
                    }
                } 
            }



            /**
             * @name TestDataFactory
             * @description Contains methods to construct and/or validate commonly used records
            **/
            public with sharing class TestDataFactory {

                /**
                 * @name ConstructCollaborationGroup
                 * @description
                **/
                
                 public static User CreateTestUser() {
                    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User' LIMIT 1];
                    User u = new User(
                        FirstName = 'Test',
                        LastName = 'User',
                        Email = 'testuser@example.com',
                        Alias = 'tuser',
                        Username = 'testuser@example.com',
                        CommunityNickname = 'TestUser',
                        TimeZoneSidKey = 'America/Los_Angeles',
                        LocaleSidKey = 'en_US',
                        EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8',
                        ProfileId = p.Id,
                        LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US'
                    );
                    return u;
                }
                
                public static CollaborationGroup ConstructCollaborationGroup(){
                    return new CollaborationGroup(CollaborationType='Public',Name='TEST'+constants.INVENTORY_ANNOUNCEMENTS);

                    //ToDo: Ensure this method returns a single Chatter CollaborationGroup
                    //    whose Name starts with 'TEST' followed by the INVENTORY_ANNOUNCEMENTS constant
                    //    and configured so anyone can join, see and post updates.
                }

                /**
                 * @name CreateProducts
                 * @description Constructs a list of Product2 records for unit tests
                **/
                public static list<Product2> ConstructProducts(Integer cnt){
                    list<Product2> prods = new list<Product2>();

                    for(integer i=0;i<cnt;i++){
                        prods.add(new Product2(Name='Product'+i,IsActive=true,Initial_Inventory__c=10, family = Constants.PRODUCT_FAMILY.get(math.mod(i, Constants.PRODUCT_FAMILY.size())).getValue()));
                    }
                    return prods;
                    //ToDo: Ensure this method returns a list, of size cnt, of uniquely named Product2 records
                    //  with all the required fields populated
                    //  and IsActive = true
                    //  an Initial Inventory set to 10
                    //  and iterating through the product family picklist values throughout the list.
                }

                /**
                 * @name CreatePricebookEntries
                 * @description Constructs a list of PricebookEntry records for unit tests
                **/
                public static List<PricebookEntry> ConstructPricebookEntries(List<Product2> prods){

                    List<PricebookEntry> entries = new List<PricebookEntry>();
                    for(integer i=0;i<prods.size();i++){
                        entries.add(new PricebookEntry(product2Id = prods.get(i).Id, Pricebook2Id = constants.STANDARD_PRICEBOOK_ID, UnitPrice = 12, IsActive = true));
                    }
                    return entries;

                    //ToDo: Ensure this method returns a corresponding list of PricebookEntries records
                    //  related to the provided Products
                    //  with all the required fields populated
                    //  and IsActive = true
                    //  and belonging to the standard Pricebook
                }

                /**
                 * @name CreateAccounts
                 * @description Constructs a list of Account records for unit tests
                **/
                public static list<Account>  ConstructAccounts(Integer cnt){
                    list<Account> accs = new list<Account>();

                    for(integer i=0;i<cnt;i++){
                        accs.add(new Account(Name='Account'+i));
                    }
                    return accs;
                    //ToDo: Ensure this method returns a list of size cnt of uniquely named Account records
                    //  with all of the required fields populated.
                }

                /**
                 * @name CreateContacts
                 * @description Constructs a list of Contacxt records for unit tests
                **/
                public static List<Contact> ConstructContacts(Integer cnt, List<Account> accts){
                    List<Contact> cs = new list<Contact>();

                    for(integer i=0;i<cnt;i++){
                            cs.add(new Contact(FirstName='Fname'+i,LastName='Lname'+i,AccountId=accts.get(math.mod(i, accts.size())).Id));
                    }
                        
                    return cs;

                    //ToDo: Ensure this method returns a list, of size cnt, of uniquely named Contact records
                    //  related to the provided Accounts
                    //  with all of the required fields populated.
                }

                /**
                 * @name CreateOrders
                 * @description Constructs a list of Order records for unit tests
                **/
                public static List<Order> ConstructOrders(Integer cnt, List<Account> accts){
                    List<Order> cs = new list<Order>();

                   for(integer i=0;i<cnt;i++){
                            cs.add(new Order(status='Draft',EffectiveDate= System.today(),AccountId=accts.get(math.mod(i, accts.size())).Id,Pricebook2Id=Constants.STANDARD_PRICEBOOK_ID));
                    }
                        
                    return cs;

                    //ToDo: Ensure this method returns a list of size cnt of uniquely named Order records
                    //  related to the provided Accounts
                    //  with all of the required fields populated.
                }

                /**
                 * @name CreateOrderItems
                 * @description Constructs a list of OrderItem records for unit tests
                **/
                public static List<OrderItem> ConstructOrderItems(integer cnt, list<pricebookentry> pbes, list<order> ords){
                    List<OrderItem> cs = new list<OrderItem>();

                    for(integer i=0;i<cnt;i++){
                        OrderItem oi = new OrderItem();
                        oi.Quantity = Constants.DEFAULT_ROWS;
                        oi.OrderId = ords.get(math.mod(i, ords.size())).Id;
                        oi.PricebookEntryId = pbes.get(math.mod(i, pbes.size())).Id;
                        oi.UnitPrice = 250;
                        cs.add(oi);
                    }
                    
                    return cs;
                    
                    //ToDo: Ensure this method returns a list of size cnt of OrderItem records
                    //  related to the provided Pricebook Entries
                    //  and related to the provided Orders
                    //  with all of the required fields populated.
                    //  Hint: Use the DEFAULT_ROWS constant for Quantity as it will be used in the next challenge
                }

                /**
                 * @name SetupTestData
                 * @description Inserts accounts, contacts, Products, PricebookEntries, Orders, and OrderItems.
                **/
                public static void InsertTestData(Integer cnt){
                    INSERT ConstructCollaborationGroup();
                    list<Account> accs = ConstructAccounts(cnt);
                    INSERT accs;

                    INSERT ConstructContacts(cnt,accs);

                    list<Product2> prods = ConstructProducts(cnt);
                    INSERT prods;
                    
                    list<PriceBookEntry> ents =ConstructPricebookEntries(prods);
                    INSERT ents;
                    
                    list<Order> ords = ConstructOrders(cnt, accs);
                    INSERT ords;

                    INSERT ConstructOrderItems(cnt, ents, ords);

                    //ToDo: Ensure this method calls each of the construct methods
                    //  and inserts the results for use as test data.

                }

                public static void VerifyQuantityOrdered(Product2 originalProduct, Product2 updatedProduct, Integer qtyOrdered){
                    System.assertEquals(updatedProduct.Quantity_Ordered__c, originalProduct.Quantity_Ordered__c + qtyOrdered);
                }
            }
```

Comment: which is line 166 in the test factory class?? when I copied the above code, line 166 wasn't even in the method `InsertTestData` and how is `CONSTANTS.STANDARD_PRICEBOOK_ID` defined?

Comment: So i was working on test class and i also got the same issue months back, issue was that i was hardcoding the id of a record  that was deleted or not present in the org and inserting that record after insertion error came `insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []`,  also an cause of error can be is the id is malformed and you maybe tryna insert a malformed id.

Comment: this resolved the issue ,thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was working on test class and i also got the same issue months back,

issue was, that i was hardcoding the `id` of a `record` that was **deleted or not present in the org and inserting that record** after insertion error came as `insufficient access rights on cross-reference id: []`, also an cause of error can be is the id is malformed and you maybe tryna insert a malformed id.

Please verify if you are not inserting any hardcoded Id in your test class